# Independent search tool that returns exact match of a post title

Tags: search

I would like to create a very simple search tool that works independently of the regular search.

The concept is simple, search all titles of a particular post type for an EXACT match, if it finds a match go straight to the post. If not, return no match found.

I'm sure this is incredibly simple but I'm struggling.  I've tried to loop through the results of $wp_query if is_search() is true, but that relies on the existing search tool and I really want them separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sent me in the right direction.  Here is what I have came up with.  I decided to create a shortcode so I can drop this anywhere needed.  Using the get_page_by_title() also allowed me to find posts even if their post type was hidden from the traditional search.

```
function esm_search($atts) {
        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
                "label_codeword" => 'Codeword',
                "label_submit" => 'Submit'
        ), $atts));

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
                $error = false;
                foreach ($_POST as $field => $value) {
                        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
                                $value = stripslashes($value);
                        }
                        $form_data[$field] = strip_tags($value);
                }

                if( $form_data['codeword'] != "") {
                        $esmID = get_page_by_title($form_data['codeword'],"","esm" );
                        if( $esmID ) {
                                wp_redirect( get_permalink( $esmID ) );
                        }else{
                                $result = 'That codeword doesn\'t exist.';
                        }

                }else{
                        $result = "Please enter a codeword.";
                }
        }

        if( $result != "" ) {
                $info = '<div class="info">'.$result.'</div>';
        }

        $esm_form = '<form method="post" action="'.get_permalink().'">
                <div>
                        <input type="text" name="codeword" id="esm_codeword" size="6" maxlength="6" value="'.$form_data['codeword'].'" />
                </div>
                <div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Sumbit" name="send" id="esm_send" />
                </div>
        </form>';

        if($sent == true) {
                return $info;
        } else {
                return $info.$esm_form;
        }
}
```

P.S. I used [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/creating-a-simple-contact-form-for-simple-needs--wp-27893) as a template for the code.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually pretty annoying to bend `WP_Query` for it. However there is convenient [`get_page_by_title()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_page_by_title/) function that can do just that. Despite the name it allows you to pass other post types as third argument.